# Risks of MongoDB size estimation

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have seen a lot of Topics on how to estimate/calculate the 
size of an DB or more specificly on a MongoDB.

Most of these topics are closed before some usefull information is given. 
I would like to get a list of all factors/risks that we need to keep in mind
when calculating the size of a MongoDB.

- Database size
- Indexes (Database size * 2 as understood from other posts.)
- Pre-allocation (about 2GB?)
- To be save always calculate with full Documents, your full model

Can anybody extend this list or confirm that it's true what i'm saying here?

If we have a list that is confirmed by multiple persons, than i will accept it as anwser.

Comment: Questions about administrating and managing databases fit much better on http://dba.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: The biggest risk to estimation of storage usage is actually your data model and use case. For a given data set size there can be a large variance in storage size depending on the efficiency of your use case. It doesn't boil down to a mathematical formula: you need to do some proof of concept with your own data model. I suspect the prior topics are closed for similar reasons: there isn't a good generic answer and advice may be misleading. For example, indexes as twice database size is a very useless estimate: what sort of indexes are you creating (compound, geo, text) and how big are the keys?

Comment: @Stennie please set your comment as an answer and i will accept it. Because i totally agree.